# Receive Gmail from Linux command line and save to file

Tags: linux, email, command-line, gmail

What I'd like to achieve:

Command line Gmail email client waiting for emails to come, and upon email arrival saves the contents of the mail to a text file in a specified path.

Anyone knows of a tool or a tutorial that shows how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `fetchmail` and `procmail`.

- `fetchmail` fetches messages from remote mailbox using `POP3` or `IMAP` protocols.
- `fetchmail` may execute custom command to process fetched messages e.g. `procmail` (see `fetchmail`'s `--mda` command line option)
- `procmail` can deliver messages to mailbox files, maildir directories, mh folders and/or execute custom command based on received message content
- `fetchmail` supports `IMAP IDLE` command - it allows to keep `IMAP` session open and receive new messages in monitored `IMAP` folder in near real time